# How to configure com.sun.net.httpserver to remove wildcard binding?

Tags: java, rest, com.sun.net.httpserver

I am using the com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer to expose a REST API in a kubernates microservice. Till now it was with wildcard binding. I need to remove the wildcard binding to bind this to its local IP

I am using the com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer to expose a REST API in a kubernates microservice. Till now i had been using

```
httpServer = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://localhost:" + port + "/"", resourceConfig, false); 
httpServer.start();
```

With this the port would be having a wildcard binding through which anyone can connect.

I have a requirement now to remove the wildcard binding from this port and have modified my code to below

```
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress();
InetSocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(localHost, port);
httpServer = com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create();
httpServer.bind(sockAddr,5);
httpServer.start();
```

With the above code, I see that the wildcard binding has got removed ([::ffff:127.0.0.1]:) but the API is not accessible from within the pod or outside.

Edit( Tried this code as well)

```
InetSocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress(localHost, port);
httpServer = com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create();
httpServer.bind(sockAddr,5);
httpServer.start();
```

With the above code netstat shows * binding but Error 404 is not seen. Instead the curl command never comes out.

Can someone please point out the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `server.createContext` method to register your own HTTP request handler and finish the HTTP request by yourself.

For example:

```java
var server = com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create();
server.createContext("/", exchange -> {
    try(var os = exchange.getResponseBody())
    {
        var buffer = "hello world".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, buffer.length);
        os.write(buffer);
        os.flush();
    }
});
```

In addition, if you want to request that server in any web broswer, you will have to handle response headers by yourself (via calling `exchange.getResponseHeaders().add("xxx", "xxx")`) and handle [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) to solve CORS policy problems.